# Matplotlib: Multiple Histograms in One Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several histograms that I want to include in a single figure.  I know I can do this:

```
plt.title("Mondays")
plt.hist(mon["price"], bins=50, alpha=0.5, histtype='bar', ec='black')
plt.show()
```

But if I add another `plt.hist(...)` before calling `plt.show()`, matplotlib adds the second histogram on top of the first one.  I'd like separate subplots for each of `mon["price"], tues["price"], ..., sun["price"]`.

How would I go about that?

Comment: Did you look through the [Matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) for figures with multiple sub-plots and try to adapt the example code to your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subplots as in this example: [matplotlob documentation 2 plots](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplot-py)

plt.subplot(211) means: 2 rows, 1 column, 1:this is the 1st plot.

Here is an example with 4 plots: 2 rows and 2 columns:
[4 plots](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-scales-py)